# Textarea autogrow not working for oninput event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea where text wrap works fine and also I have written autogrow code in javascript which increases the height of textarea instead of scroll if the text wraps as shown in the snippet.

But the problem I am facing is that, when I pass the value to the textarea using `document.getElementById` on body load,textarea size doesn't increase automatically, but when I input any charachter, text area size automatically increases. 
As per my understanding as soon any charachter is typed in textarea, an event should be generated right?

Please correct me if I have gone wrong anywhere in the code?

Advance Thanks!

```js
document.getElementById("fee1").value = "text";

function auto_grow(element) {
 
    element.style.height = "5px";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

```html
<textarea form ='billsave' class= 'form-control input-sm ftype feet' rows='1' id = 'fee1' name= 'feetype' oninput='auto_grow(this)' required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to fire `oninput()` event manually after setting the text.

```js
document.getElementById("fee1").value = "text";
document.getElementById("fee1").oninput()

function auto_grow(element) {
    element.style.height = "5px";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

```html
<textarea form ='billsave' class= 'form-control input-sm ftype feet' rows='1' id = 'fee1' name= 'feetype' oninput='auto_grow(this)' required></textarea>
```